# Finding value of variables

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Sorry, this might be a trivial question. I have two mathematical equations as follows:

$$ \left(\frac{M}{D_1}\right)\left(\frac{D_1}{R}\right)=L\  \text{and}\   \left(\frac{M}{D_2}\right)\left(\frac{D_2}{R}\right)=L.$$

The values of $R, D_1$ and $ D_2 $ are available, however, need to find the values of $ L$ and $M$. Does having more such equations with $D_i$ help to get the values of $L$ and $M$?

Thanks.

Comment: You have an infinite amount of solutions because you can only get $L =\frac{M}{R}$ so depending on $R$ - since it does not appear that any of these are varying - then $L/M$ is a constant

Comment: You should clarify what kind of things (real numbers?) the unknowns $L$ and $M$ are assumed to be (presumably the same kinds of things as knowns $R$ and $D_i$).  It is possible that your notation was meant to be for [Legendre symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any equation of the form $(\dfrac{M}{D_i})(\dfrac{D_i}{R})=L$ will get reduced to $\dfrac{M}{R}=L$ regardless of the value of $D_i$ (as long as $D_i\neq0$). Hence, even if you have an infinite number of $D_i$, they will all be reduced to $\dfrac{M}{R}=L$, so it won't help. Besides, if we only know the value of $R$, there are infinitely many solutions, since $(M, L)=(xR, x)$ works for any $x\in\mathbb{C}$.